# HomeBrew is not working after upgrading mac OS to mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, homebrew, updates

Recently, I have upgraded my mac from 10.8 to Mavericks then when I tried 
`brew update` but it is not working as expected so I want to remove that from my mac completely then re-install.

> Can Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing /usr/local/ and reloading from a clean state solves the problem. Odd but it helps.